# Jquery if scroll is a certain amount of pixels

Tags: jquery, scroll

Is there a built in jQuery function to determine the length of a scroll?

I'm trying to write a function that will add a class to a div if the user has scrolled 50 pixels from the top.

So the code will look like this:

```
if(userHasScrolled) {
     $('#myDiv').addClass('hasScrolled');

}
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can check `$(document).scrollTop()` inside of a scroll handler:

```
var $document = $(document),
    $element = $('#some-element'),
    className = 'hasScrolled';

$document.scroll(function() {
  if ($document.scrollTop() >= 50) {
    // user scrolled 50 pixels or more;
    // do stuff
    $element.addClass(className);
  } else {
    $element.removeClass(className);
  }
});
```

If adding the class name is all you want (no other actions needed), this could be shortened to:

```
var $document = $(document),
    $element = $('#some-element'),
    className = 'hasScrolled';

$document.scroll(function() {
  $element.toggleClass(className, $document.scrollTop() >= 50);
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/.

Note that it is very inefficient to use `scroll` event handlers.

Comment: In this case I like to use the [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method for brevity: `$element.toggleClass(className, $document.scrollTop() >= 50);`

Comment: @Geert If adding the class name is all you want, that’s indeed the most elegant solution!

Comment: Above Solution is not working properly for iOS devices, event is getting fired  only after scroll stop.