# How can I change the height of several classes with one single class?

Tags: html, css

for all the classes below I have set a fixed height of 120px. Is there a way to control the height of all of them with one single class (class or something else) ? 
I know I could do .header, .logo, .etc { height: 120px } and remove the the height from all the individual items but that would still not look like the most efficient solution. Thanks

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #124191;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 28px;
    display: table;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999999;
}

.logo {
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 120px; /* this is set to same height as the div */
    left:0;
    height:120px;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 800;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    margin-left: 60px;
}

 .drop_menu {
    background:red;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    height:120px;
    right: 0;
    display: table;
    z-index: 3000;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Check: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148310/jquery-if-scroll-is-a-certain-amount-of-pixels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148310/jquery-if-scroll-is-a-certain-amount-of-pixels)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have to use javascript for this, because CSS simply won't cover the type of interaction you want. First of all, if you want to set the height of several classes to one value simultaneously, you have two options:

1. Change the height of every single class using Javascript or jQuery. For example: `$(".header, .logo, .dropmenu").height("80px");`.
2. Make toggle a new class that applies to all elements. For example, if your class was defined as `newClass {height: 80px;}`, then you could do `$(".header, .logo, .dropmenu").toggleClass("newClass");`

See [this link](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) for more info about multiple selectors, and [this link](http://api.jquery.com/height/) for more info about changing height, and finally [this link](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) for more info about toggling a class with jQuery. Of course, there are ways of doing this with just stock Javascript, but I personally prefer jQuery because it simplifies everything up a lot.

As for applying a class when [scrolled](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) to a [certain height](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) the following code or something similar could suffice:

```
$(".header, .logo, .dropmenu").scroll(function(){
    if ($(".header, .logo, .dropmenu").scrollTop > 20){
      $(".header, .logo, .dropmenu").toggleClass("newClass");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give one class to all three elements in html like

`<div class="logo some_other_class">`
`<div class="header some_other_class">`
`<div class="dropmenu some_other_class">`

and if you are using jquery you can change height like:

`$(".some_other_class").css("height", "80px");`