# How do I make an element fade out on Scroll - my code worked elsewhere but not here

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I've got a bootstrap landing page with code that I took from a different project to fade out the navbar when scrolling part way down the screen & fade back in when scrolling to the top. It worked flawlessly on a navbar element.
On this project, I changed the context and I'm trying to get target an h2 to fade out on scrolling down and back in when scroll to top.

Here is my Code:

```js
function checkScroll() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 200) {
      $('.name-text').addClass('.my-name');
  } else {
      $('.name-text').removeClass('.my-name');
  }
}
```

```css
.landing {  
  position: relative; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100vh; 
  z-index: -1;  
}

.home-wrap {   
  clip: rect(0, auto, auto, 0);  
  position: absolute; 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;  
  left: 0;
}

.home-inner {
  background-image: url(/img/hero.jpg); 
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  will-change: transform;
  overflow: hidden; 
}

/* Caption - Landing Page */
.name-text {
    z-index: 13 !important;
    color: #75e3ff !important;
    text-shadow: .2rem .2rem .3rem #fff;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 1s ease;
}

.my-name {
  color: #4caf4f00 !important;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .2 ease;
}

.caption {
  z-index: 10;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 57%; 
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.caption::before  {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 2000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: hidden;
} 

.caption h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-shadow: .1rem .1rem .8rem #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="landing">
  <div class="home-wrap">
    <div class="home-inner">
      <div class="home-inner text-center text-light text-uppercase">
        <h2 class="text-center p-5 m-3 name-text">Text I want to fade out on Scroll</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- =============== Hero Text ==================== -->
  <div class="caption text-center text-light text-uppercase p-5">
    
    <h1 class="font-weight-light animate__animated animate__bounceInUp animate__fast">Portfolio</h1>

    <h3 class="animate__animated animate__bounceInUp">Here you will find a wee bit o' info on me & my projects</h3>

  </div>
  
</section>

<div>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate blanditiis excepturi, expedita aliquam at quod dolores soluta sunt mollitia temporibus ipsum nesciunt, laudantium eos minima voluptatum. Aspernatur nesciunt consectetur nisi dolorem laudantium! Dignissimos, odit, nam ratione soluta hic inventore impedit obcaecati sed repellendus similique architecto quidem rem deserunt, consequatur assumenda eligendi. Excepturi dolor eaque praesentium cum enim quo suscipit, temporibus molestias ab nemo. Officiis aperiam facilis exercitationem iusto ab culpa expedita totam est, sequi rem tempore laboriosam velit id vero dolores aspernatur quae delectus labore, molestiae quasi eaque deserunt. Maiores corporis ratione consequatur placeat omnis. Nemo modi rerum ducimus asperiores.
Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate blanditiis excepturi, expedita aliquam at quod dolores soluta sunt mollitia temporibus ipsum nesciunt, laudantium eos minima voluptatum. Aspernatur nesciunt consectetur nisi dolorem laudantium! Dignissimos, odit, nam ratione soluta hic inventore impedit obcaecati sed repellendus similique architecto quidem rem deserunt, consequatur assumenda eligendi. Excepturi dolor eaque praesentium cum enim quo suscipit, temporibus molestias ab nemo. Officiis aperiam facilis exercitationem iusto ab culpa expedita totam est, sequi rem tempore laboriosam velit id vero dolores aspernatur quae delectus labore, molestiae quasi eaque deserunt. Maiores corporis ratione consequatur placeat omnis. Nemo modi rerum ducimus asperiores.</div>
```

Comment: Based on this, you're declaring the function but are you actually calling it anywhere?

Comment: This should help direct you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148310/jquery-if-scroll-is-a-certain-amount-of-pixels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do instead is run the function on window:

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll > 110) {
    $('.name-text').addClass('.my-name');
  } else {
    $('.name-text').removeClass('.my-name');
  }
});
```

This way the code is reacting to the scroll listening for the change in position.